# Random numbers in R (1) with specified mean, sd, (2) within specified range

Tags: r, random

I would like to generate random numbers with both a specified mean & sd, AND a specified min and/or max (i.e., give me 100 random numbers between 0 and 50 with a mean=20 and sd=10; OR give me 100 random numbers with min=10, mean=25, sd=15).

I can specify  mean & sd in runif, rnorm.
I can specify a range in sample (though I don't think I can specify ONLY a min or a max)

I need something where I can specify both, in R.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the R package truncdist which allows you to create truncated distributions, which in your case would be a truncated normal distribution with mean 20, sd 10, and upper and lower bounds of 0 and 50.

Comment: Thanks @qdread. truncdist allows me to specify min, max and distribution shape, but it appears not mean and sd. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you can specify the parameters, you pass the additional arguments to dtrunc() that would go to dnorm() or whatever distribution you choose. For example in your case `rtrunc(n = 100, spec = 'norm', a = 0, b = 50, mean = 20, sd = 10)`

Comment: For your second case if you specify no value for `b` it will default to `Inf` for infinity so you will get only the minimum truncation.

Comment: Which distribution do you need? All of them, or just normal and/or uniform? [`truncnorm`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=truncnorm`) gives a statistically rigorous truncated normal distribution.

Comment: See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/56750/163114

Comment: Thanks qdread r2evans jay.sf. rtrunc  did what I needed.